# Android Custom Keyboard "Next" to "Done" Button

Tags: android, keyboard

I am making a custom keyboard, but I am having an issue with the Next/Done button.

I have two `EditText` boxes on the screen.  The first has the IMEption set to show the Next button and the second has the IMEOption set to show the Done button.  If I touch into either one and the custom keyboard's `onStartInput` method is called the button is labeled correctly.

But when I touch into the first `EditText` box and then "Next" to the second box the button stays as Next and not Done as it should be.

How can I have the keyboard pull the `EditorInfo` of the `EditText` it is in to relabel the Next/Done button?

Thanks
Adam